# PHP preg_replace add comma

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is my code

```
$keywords = mysql_escape_string(preg_replace("/[^ \w]+/", '',($_POST['keywords'])));
```

and this my output

```
sample products products sample
```

Here I don't want to replace comma also.

The input is

```
sample products!@, products#$#, sample
```

Comment: You mean like `"/[^ \w,]+/"`.... is this really rocket science?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to get rid of `,`s, you can add them to your group in the square brackets:

```
preg_replace("/[^, \w]+/", '',($_POST['keywords']))
```

Comment: Correct, but you're missing a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$keywords = preg_replace("/[^A-Z, ]/i", '',($_POST['keywords']));
echo $keywords;
```

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/qdUDJ)

**Note**: this replaces the content which does not match with the regex. Here it replaces anything except alpabets(case in-sensitive ) and comma `,` and blank space

Comment: This would change what is qualified as a match since `\w` also matches underscores.

Comment: yes correct , based on assumption he need only alphabets and `,` i have written this regex

Comment: Still, he/she may need them to be included for one reason or another so you should at least warn the op that the matches may be different.